# Matlab Fatal Error on startup: std::exception: dlopen(libncurses.dylib, 10): image not found: No such file or directory

Tags: matlab

I am trying to open Matlab from Terminal on Mac using the following command:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay
```

It works well on Matlab 2015a, b, 2014a, b.

But with Matlab 2016b on a new computer, I got this error message:

> Fatal Error on startup: std::exception: dlopen(libncurses.dylib, 10): image not found: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell Matlab explicitly where the library is located.

Run this line in the Terminal before you startup Matlab:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```